Rigid body simulation keeps wiggling
I've got a large mess of a few hundred identical parts (torus), all intertwined, all using "Shape=mesh".  When I drop it on a floor, it lands ok - but then it continues to thrash around and crawl away.  Which is not what I expected, and creepy as heck.
Is there a setting that will make it less wiggly once it is in a near-resting position?  Imposing a "you are now moving through thick soup" sort of dampener starting at frame 500?
I've already got friction and bounciness down to 0.1, and margin at the default 0.04m.

It's usually called "damping" in simulations. It works for any frames, there is no specific solution for frame 500.

Can you post an image or gif? If I'm understanding correctly, you have a chain, and the collisions between the links make it bounce around? You could try playing with the deactivation thresholds. It's possible increasing them would help the object come to rest, OR it's possible that objects sleeping when they still have a bit of motion is contributing to the instability of the system

In general, I think the term you want to search is "rigid body instability". You might also try looking for advice for bullet3d, which is the name of the physics sim blender uses under the hood.

The other thing to consider is: you are asking blender to do a lot of complicated physics calculations to model the interactions between a bunch of links of chain with mesh collision. You can probably get something visually quite similar using a bunch of capsule colliders, bound together by generic constraints that limit their translation and rotation to keep them more-or-less interlinked. It won't be as accurate, but it'll still make a convincing chain, and will likely be much more stable.

In the Scene Properties under Rigid Body World, increase the Substeps Per Frame to maybe 20 or 30.

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
